# Image not spanning the whole width on Apple devices

Tags: ios, css, wordpress

I am developing a WordPress theme at the site;

DELETED

I have a slider at the top which is suppose to spanning the width of the device which is does for Windows and Android devices. However, for Apple devices, Mac, iPad, iPhone it is contrained to the width of the main content at 1280px.

The HTML/PHP code is

```
<div class="full-width page-style">

        <?php 

            if( have_posts() ):

                while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

                    <?php the_content(); ?>

                <?php endwhile;

            endif;

        ?>

</div>
```

The CSS is

```
.full-width {
    max-width: 1280px;
    overflow: inherit;
    padding: 0px 25px!important;
    background: transparent!important;
    border: none!important;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.page-style {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 25px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    min-height: 800px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I have tried to edit both the code and CSS to no avail, and I have also tried to inspect the page below to see if I can figure out how they achieved it;

http://layouts.siteorigin.com/layout/fitness-gym/

The issue definately lies with the HTML/CSS mark up rather than the content. I think I must be missing something simple in my HTML for Apple devices.

Comment: Just a little confused. The site you linked shows a slider with a background image that spans the full width of the browser just fine. I am viewing it on a mac. The content is constrained to 1280px, but that seems intended since you have the max-width of .full-width set at 1280px.

Comment: @JamesHamann That so that the content after the slider is within 1280px, but the slider should be the whole width? It's the same on the site I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it was a javascript error that Apple devices did not like, once the error was resolved it was all ok.

Answer (score 0):

Last edit. What if you gave the "panel-grid" div which contains the slider:

```
margin-left:-25px;
margin-right:-25px;
```

This will pull the slider out past the padding created by .full-width. Theoretically.

Comment: Can't it's generated by WordPress.

Comment: Ah, the joys of wordpress. Edited my answer. Hope that helps. If not, then I am out of ideas. Good luck.